# Is GP a British only term?

Tags: discussion

I have added a comment explaining why I closed [here](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/247/rashes-on-back-of-knees#comment239_247):

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is localised and is unlikely to help other people. If you are worried about a health condition, see your GP / Doctor. –  Tim

In it, I decided to use the phrase GP (General Practitioner). However, I am worried now that that is a British only term. Should we be using Doctor, GP or some other international expression?

Comment: It depends if they're Jews or Christians, see: [OMG… A site about Health](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/27/114) :)

Comment: @Kenorb I'm both, I use GP or doctor :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm in the states and commonly use "GP". "Family doctor" is more common though.

Comment: So just doctor is better for this site?

Comment: @Tim That's what I'd use, but I would bother editing others' posts to chance GP to Doctor.

Answer (score 1):

Wiki says about [GP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_practitioner):

> The term general practitioner or **GP** is common in the Republic of Ireland, the United Kingdom and several Commonwealth countries. In these countries the word physician is largely reserved for certain other types of medical specialists, notably in internal medicine. While in these countries, the term GP has a clearly defined meaning, in North America the term has become somewhat ambiguous, and is not necessarily synonymous with the term "**family doctor**" or primary care provider, as described below.

On [Family medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_medicine):

> In Europe the discipline is often referred to as general practice and a practitioner as a General Practice Doctor or GP; this name emphasises the holistic nature of this speciality, as well as its roots in the family.

Based on above it seems GP is used across many English speaking countries including Europe, not only in the UK.